# Automator and bash shell script to insert text

Tags: bash, shell, automator

I am setting an Automator quick action to execute a .sh script.
This .sh script renames a file by prompting the user to insert text to add at the end of the filename.

I have this so far:

```
[workflow receives files of folders]

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "/path-to-my-script.sh" in window 1
end tell
```

This opens the terminal, but it does not prompt me to write any text.
Not sure what I am missing. 
Thanks!

P.S.: My script is just:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@"
do
/pathtomyfuntion "$f"
done
```

When I execute I get this error:

```
File my function/__init__.py", line 386, in main
    text = input('Please enter text: ').strip()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

So it's precisely the prompt at Terminal what I can't manage to get right.

Comment: So what does your `.sh` script contain?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for f in "$@"
do
/pathtomyfunction "$f"
done

Comment: You don't appear to call your script with any arguments, so why should it do anything?

Comment: Could you tell me how? I am no programmer, I managed to put those bits together by googling for couple days :D

Comment: The workflow works with files as input and calls the script. The script has the argument $f which takes in the files. When I run the script on the terminal, it takes the file and prompts me for a name to rename it. But when run from automator, it opens the terminal, I guess it takes in the file but it does not prompt to type any name to rename those files.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232205/how-to-create-an-automator-service-to-run-a-script-on-all-files-in-a-folder --> this might help you.

Comment: Will have a look, thanks.

Comment: Did not help. The problem I get is: File my function/__init__.py", line 386, in main
    text = input('Please enter text: ').strip()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: If you're just trying to rename files with a quick action, there are far easier ways to do it in automator. is there something else involved here, or can I offer a better solution?

Comment: It's a specific rename action, so I want to learn how to do this and also to apply it to future actions.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein: that didn't really answer my question, so I assume you don't want a different solution, and I won't provide one.  I will point out, though, that instead of using `Run Shell Script` to execute a python script, you could just use Automator's `Run Python Script` action. Save yourself some confusion...

Comment: Hi @TedWrigley, thanks. I answer more in depth: my function takes a file(s) and prompts me for a text that it will append to each file before the extension. So it does it on Terminal. I haven't found the way to do this. What would be the difference between using Run Python Script and Run Shell Script? I call my python function from Terminal. BTW, I have no Run Python Script in my Automator list of actions.

Comment: `Run Python Script` may have been introduced in Catalina; you don't say what OS you're on. it's just simpler to run the python script directly that to run it within a bash shell, and simpler is usually better.

Comment: However, if *all* you're doing is adding text before the extension, Automator has an action that is explicitly designed to do that — `Rename Finder Items` — so I don't know why you're struggling to implement a python script.

Comment: Incidentally, do you need each file edited separately, or are you addicting the same text into *all* the file names?

Comment: My rename function is more sophisticated than the inbuilt rename action. It will read EXIF info and other things, it will pop a window to add extra tags, etc. The idea is to select many files and assign the same value, so yes.

Comment: Got it; I'm seeing the bigger picture now. Part of the problem, I think, is that automator is designed to be *modular*, and you're working against that modularity by trying to do everything within a single called script, but that's not necessarily insurmountable. Let me think on it a bit.